My ubuntu 24.04.1 cannot detect any sound hardware. dummy output device
i have just about searched every forums and tried all the solutions including removing reinstalling pipewire, pulseaudio alsa and everything. i have already watched most of the tutorials. i dont know what to do please help.
my device is acer aspire lite 16 i51235U 12th gen.
just help me anyone

Use lspci -v | grep -i audio and aplay -l in a terminal then edit your question with the results as text not picture, and do not add them in comments.

Details matter. What have you tried be exact? What errors or message does each try produce? Watched what tutorials?
